# Schedule emails using Spring boot and Quartz

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, jobs

I would Like to send emails daily using Spring boot, the user specifies the time of sending, I used quartz to schedule my Job. The recipients of emails have(id, emailAddress, deadline) The email will be sent to the people who have deadline = Today + X.. (The user specifies the X). For example: The user specifies that X is number 1, so we're interested in people who have deadline tomorow.

Day1: the app sent emails to people who have deadline = today +1..
Day2: I want that the application send the email at Day2 to new recipients, but with the code below, the email is sent to the same recipients of Day1, and that's not what I need.

```
@PostMapping("/**")
    public ResponseEntity<ScheduleEmailResponse> SendScheduleEmailPeriodic(
            @Valid @RequestBody PeriodicNotification scheduleEmailRequest) throws Exception {
        ens.schedulePeriodicNotification(scheduleEmailRequest);
        LocalDate localDateTime = LocalDate.now();
        LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(scheduleEmailRequest.getSendingTime());

        

        try {
            ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, localTime,ZoneId.of("**"));
            if (dateTime.isBefore(ZonedDateTime.now())) {
                ScheduleEmailResponse scheduleEmailResponse = new ScheduleEmailResponse(false,
                        "dateTime must be after current time");
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(scheduleEmailResponse);
            }

            JobDetail jobDetail = buildPeriodicJobDetail(scheduleEmailRequest);
            Trigger trigger = buildJobTriggerPeriodic(jobDetail, dateTime);
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);

            ScheduleEmailResponse scheduleEmailResponse = new ScheduleEmailResponse(true, jobDetail.getKey().getName(),
                    jobDetail.getKey().getGroup(), "Email Scheduled Successfully!");
            return ResponseEntity.ok(scheduleEmailResponse);
        } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
            logger.error("Error scheduling email", ex);

            ScheduleEmailResponse scheduleEmailResponse = new ScheduleEmailResponse(false,
                    "Error scheduling email. Please try later!");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(scheduleEmailResponse);
        }
    }

private JobDetail buildPeriodicJobDetail(PeriodicNotification scheduleEmailRequest) {
        JobDataMap jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
        List<String> recipients = fileRepo.findWantedEmails(scheduleEmailRequest.getDaysNum());

        if(recipients.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Aucun destinataire trouvé");
        }
        String[] to = recipients.stream().toArray(String[]::new);

        jobDataMap.put("recipients", to);
        jobDataMap.put("subject", scheduleEmailRequest.getSubject());
        jobDataMap.put("body", scheduleEmailRequest.getMessage());

        return JobBuilder.newJob(EmailJob.class).withIdentity(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "email-jobs")
                .withDescription("Send Email Job").usingJobData(jobDataMap).storeDurably().build();
    }

    private Trigger buildJobTriggerPeriodic(JobDetail jobDetail, ZonedDateTime startAt) {
        return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(jobDetail)
                .withIdentity(jobDetail.getKey().getName(), "email-triggers")
                .withDescription("Send Periodic Email Trigger")
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder
                .repeatHourlyForever(24))
                .startAt(Date.from(startAt.toInstant()))
                .build();
    }
```

This is the job:

```
@Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        logger.info("Executing Job with key {}", context.getJobDetail().getKey());
        JobDataMap jobDataMap = context.getMergedJobDataMap();
        String subject = jobDataMap.getString("subject");
        String body = jobDataMap.getString("body");
        String[] recipients = (String[])jobDataMap.get("recipients");
        sendMail("**", recipients, subject, body);
        
    }
    
     private void sendMail(String fromEmail, String[] toEmail, String subject, String body) {
            try {
                logger.info("Sending Email to {}", Arrays.toString(toEmail));
                MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

                MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
                messageHelper.setSubject(subject);
                messageHelper.setText(body, true);
                messageHelper.setFrom(fromEmail);
                messageHelper.setTo(toEmail);

                mailSender.send(message);
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                logger.error("Failed to send email to {}", Arrays.toString(toEmail));
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Rest of the code looks fine, I believe you need to verify selection criteria in findWantedEmails method of FileRepo. You recipient list seem to be containing wrong IDs (Day1 in your case). Try unit testing this method first

Comment: It appears as though you are setting the recipients a job attribute so each time the job runs the recipients will be the same. Don't you want to save the 'days' in the job and query for recipients in executeInternal()?

Comment: Another option is to query for the recipients in the trigger by setting recipients as trigger job data. This will override the recipients value set when the job was created (JobDetail) with the new ones. You can find information about this here http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-03.html.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers, @Lee, I did the same but I'm still getting the same problem, could you help me with an example?

Comment: Did you call fileRepo.findWantedEmails() in executeInternal()? If so, where the same recipients as the original returned?

Comment: I cannot call findWantedEmails() in executeInternal(), I'm only getting the recipients using the jobDataMap :
  String[] recipients = (String[]) jobDataMap.get("recipients");

Comment: The contents of the jobDataMap is static unless you change it in the trigger as I mentioned above. If you expect the values to change you need to be dynamic to achieve what you want.

Comment: Do you have any Idea of how to make the contents of jobDataMap dynamic?

Comment: As I mentioned before, you would put the 'days' in the JobDataMap and call findWantedEmails() in the trigger and add them to the trigger JobDataMap using the same 'recipients' key. Or put the 'days' in the JobDataMap and call findWantedEmails() in executeInternal(). I would prefer the later approach as it's more straightforward.